What is the function that describes the hydra game?
There are several different variations of the hydra game. Here is the rules to the one I will use:

Let h be a rooted graph with finitely many points.
Let n = 1.
Select (one of) the leaf(s) furthest up the chain.*
Remove the leaf and its connecting edge.
Add n leaves to the removed leaf's grandparent.**
n increases by 1.
Repeat until the only remaining point on the graph is the root.

It has been proven that this will always end in a finite number of steps, even if you have different rules for increasing n and/or set n to much larger initial values. You could have n change to n^2, 2^n, n^n, n!, n↑↑n, n↑↑↑↑n, Graham(n), TREE(n), TREE(TREE(TREE(n))), BB(n), even Rayo(n). It will always end eventually. But how long is eventually?
For this we'll stay focused on the rules I stated above. Consider a rooted graph that is just a chain of points with no branches. Find a function whose input is the length of the chain and whose output is the value of n at the final step (to be clear, the length of the chain is the number of edges, not the number of nodes). I'd also be interested in hearing functions that act as lower or upper bounds. My original lower bound was y=x, but has since improved to 0.5(x^2)+0.5x. I've also shown that Hydra(n)<Hydra(n+1).
Lets call this function Hydra(x). I've already computed the outputs for the first 5 inputs of Hydra(x):

Hydra(1) = 1
Hydra(2) = 3
Hydra(3) = 9
Hydra(4) = 49
Hydra(5) = 1132

It is starting to get impractical to calculate these by hand, so I might code up a program in Matlab to compute these for me (if I can figure out how to write such a program).
*A leaf is a point which is not the parent of any points in a rooted graph.
**If the leaf's parent is the root of the graph and thus has no grandparent, no heads are added.

yeah that was a typo

I'm gonna fix it rn

Your $Hydra(n)$ is also the number of moves to remove $n$ layers from the end of a long chain.  I will call it $H(n)$ to save typing.  We can also define a function $L(n)$ as the number of leaves on the bottom remaining layer after $n$ layers have been removed.  $H(1)=1$ as you say because the first move removes a layer.  $L(1)=2$ because after the first move and removing a layer we add one more leaf to the newly last layer.  $H(2)$ is then $3$ because two more moves will remove the $L(1)$ leaves from the new bottom layer.  This makes $L(2)=1+2+3=6$ because moves $2$ and $3$ add those numbers of leaves to the $1$ that was there before.  Then $H(3)=9$ because it takes $L(2)=6$ more moves to chop the $6$ heads at that level.  Then $L(3)=1+4+5+6+7+8+9=40$.
We can write two coupled recurrences:
$$H(n)=H(n-1)+L(n-1)$$
$$L(n)=1+\sum_{H(n-1)+1}^{H(n-1)+L(n-1)}1=1+L(n-1)(2H(n-1)+L(n-1)+1)/2$$
A spreadsheet calculation of the first few is here

We note that $H(n) \ll L(n)$.  Once $n$ is more than a few we can ignore the small terms in $H(n), L(n)$ and get $$H(n) \approx L(n-1)\\ L(n) \approx L(n-1)^2/2$$
Taking just the $L(n)$ recurrence we can write
$$\log_2 L(n)=2 \log_2 L(n-1)-1$$
If we ignore the $-1$ we get $L(n)$ grows as $2^{2^n}$
